# I'm confused with the module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, commonjs

there are three modules: `a.js,b.js,c.js`, `a.js` is to export a database connection, and `b.js,c.js` is to import the connection just like in two different http routes, so the connection module(a.js) will be imported two times, does it mean the driver will connect to the database two times?

I have tried like this:
test.js

```
let a = 20;
let b = 30;
console.log('I am test');
let obj = {
    a,
    b
}
module.exports = obj;
```

en.js

```
let obj = require('./test');

console.log('I am en.js')

module.exports = obj;
```

hi.js

```
let obj = require('./test');
let obj2 = require('./en');

console.log(obj2)
```

run hi.js and the result:

```
I am test
I am en
{a:20,b:30}
```

en.js and the hi.js both import the test.js, from the results it seems that the test.js only runs once, so why?    Hope your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

You can read more here

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Comment: Actually modules are not merely cached. The module system properly implements the Singleton pattern. All modules on node.js are Singletons. This is much more powerful then mere caching, it means that all code importing from a module actually gets the same object. Yes, the Singleton design pattern is often used for caching but the real intent is to create a single gobal object in the process.